# Sintaxis en sap fiori

Tags: sap

Hola tengo una pregunta es que leo [aqui](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com) los objetos y librerías pero como no ponen ejemplos a veces no se exactamente como agregar un elemento no se como se declara un método, propiedad, evento o asociaciones n es que no sepa sino que no se exactamente como usarlos alguien conocer algún tutorial de **fiori en español** ?

supongamos que elijo hacer un combo box y que ya tengo cargada mi librería sap.m y mi vista la manejo con xml

suponiendo que también cargo esta librería `core` porque la quiero usar según la documentación que leo

```
xlmns:core"sap.ui.core"

<comboBox selectedItemId="Ejemplo"> (no se si aqui estoy usando bien la propiedad dentro de esta etiqueta o es aparte)
   <core:Item text="item1" > (según la documentación esta es una asociación del combobox del tipo sap.ui.core.Item)
  </core:Item>
</comboBox>
```

Tampoco se cuando cerrar la etiqueta así `<etiqueta> </etiqueta>`
o así `<etiqueta cosas />`

Comment: yo todo lo que se es que fiori solo esta en ingles, o no se si tu ya hayas encontrado algo en español y puedas compartir

Comment: Disculpa la tardanza pero tenia tiempo sin entrar por aca solo he conocido un solo blog en español que vale la pena, trabajas con fiori ?